# Appending Excel cell value in other column after calculations

Tags: excel, powershell

I wish to update a column in my Excel file after performing calculations on the cell value in another column. Basically, I will first prompt the user to ask them for a 'Yes' or 'No' answer. If they say 'Yes', I need to add 100 to all the cells in column Y and place the output in column Z. FYI, Column Y already contains pre-populated values. I am currently generating an error

```
Method invocation failed because [System.DBNull] does not contain a method
named 'op_Addition'.
At line:40 char:13
+             $cell.Value2 = $cell + $adjustment
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

```
$adjustment = 100

$Question = Read-Host "Do you have money? "
while ($worksheet.Range("Y9:Y705") -ne $null) {
    if ($Question -eq 'Yes' -or $Question -eq 'yes') {
        foreach ($cell in $worksheet.Range("Y9:Y705").Text) {
            $cell.Value2 = $cell + $adjustment
            $row = 1
            $column = 1
            Write-Host $worksheet.Range("Z9:Z705").Item($cell.Value2).value()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cite from `Get-Help about_comparison_operators` : `By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive. To make a comparison operator case-sensitive, precede the operator name with a "c".` So no need to distinct between Yes and yes.

Comment: @LotPings I see. I have already removed the comparison from my code. Thanks. However, I would like to know why my calculation is generating the above error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading. `$worksheet.Range("Y9:Y705").Text` doesn't return what you think it does. You probably intended to iterate over the content of the cells in that range, but you're actually trying to retrieve the `Text` property of the `Range` object (which is an object of the type `System.DBNull`) and then iterate over that object.

To fix the issue you need to iterate over the elements in the range.

Change this:

```
foreach ($cell in $worksheet.Range("Y9:Y705").Text) {
    $cell.Value2 = $cell + $adjustment
    ...
}
```

into this:

```
foreach ($cell in $worksheet.Range("Y9:Y705")) {
    $cell.Value2 = $cell.Value2 + $adjustment
    ...
}
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Oh, this works. But why am I generating empty values? Is it something wrong with my calculations?

Comment: @jqy You aren't generating empty values. Please read again. From the top.